# Acutalizar una celda en un d.frame que viene de otro d.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, rstudio, update

tengo 2 dataframes.

```
df1         df2
ID b c    ID b j
------    ------
1  A 3    1  R 22
2  B 4    2  S 33
3  C 5    6  V 55
4  D 6    7  W 66
```

De manera que el ID que coincida en la tabla df1 con df2 introduzca ese valor de B del df1 en el df2 y quede de esta manera

```
df2
ID b j
--------
1  A 22
2  B 33
6  V 55
7  W 66
```

he probado 2 formas si sabeis una mejor, estoy abierto.

```
sqldf(c("UPDATE df2
              Set b =(Select b_desde from df1 where df2.id= df1.Id)"))
```

En este caso no hace nada, no "actualiza ese dato"

```
   df2<- sqldf(c("UPDATE df2
                  Set b =(Select b_desde from df1 where df2.id= df1.Id)"))
```

en este caso si actualiza y hace lo que necesito pero los que no encuentra, como serian el caso ID=5 e ID=6 les pone valor NULL en vez de dejarlo como está.

Podeis decirme como solucionar esto o bien si hay alguna forma mas sencilla podeis ayudarme?
muchas gracias de antemano.
un saludo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La sentencia SQL que estas usando, efectivamente genera este problema cuando no hay coincidencia entre ambas tablas. De la siguiente forma evitarás esto ya que únicamente actualizarás las filas coincidentes en el `id`:

```
sqldf(c("UPDATE df2
              Set b = df1.b_desde 
              FROM df1
              where df1.id = df2.id",
       "select * from df2")) -> df2
```

Nota: Ten en cuenta que `sqldf` no trabaja directamente con los objetos de R sino que maneja copias internas por lo que un `update` solo actualiza los datos dentro del entorno de `sqldf`, para retornarlos, necesitas a) agregar una sentencia de selección de `df2` y b) asignar la salida de la función al objeto en R que reciba los datos, en tu caso `df2`.

Hay otras formas de resolverlo

1. Si los `id` tienen el mismo orden en ambas tablas:

   ```
   df2$b[df2$id %in% df1$id] <- df1$b_desde[df1$id %in% df2$id]
   ```
2. Usando `merge()`:

   ```
   tmp <- merge(df2, df1, by="id", all.x = TRUE)
   df2$b <- ifelse(is.na(tmp$b_desde), tmp$b, tmp$b_desde)
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Con tidyverse una posible solución es la siguiente:

```
df2 %>%
  left_join(df1, by = "ID") %>%
  mutate(b = ifelse(is.na(b.y), b.x, b.y)) %>%
  select(names(df2))
```

Cruzamos ambas df por "ID", lo que por defecto te creara dos variables b un b.x y un b.y , ya que coincide su nombre, luego con el ifelse los elementos que no encuentre en b.y los tomara de b.x y finalmente en el select ordenamos el df con los nombres originales de df2